# Is there a way to run CoffeeScript natively in Terminal?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Since we can run JavaScript using various interpreters, like V8 or Rhino, I thought there should be a way to run CoffeeScript code inside a terminal as well.

Technically, I can do that by using Node.js while running javascript, but I'm curious if there is a standalone interpreter specifically designed for CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can launch a coffeescript file with `coffee filename`, but this will just compile the coffeescript file in-RAM and run it as javascript. Well, actually someone did write an interpreter for coffeescript, but that interpreter is written in javascript or coffeescript or so and therefore has to run inside of a JS engine, too. Also, it's slow as hell because it's an interpreter and not a JIT compiler.

As I said, just use the `coffee` command.

Answer (score 9):

What's wrong with simply installing and running the interpreter that comes with CoffeeScript itself?

Read the installation part of the guide here: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#installation

And then use it like this:

[image]

Or am I missing some dimension of your question?

Comment: I believe the questioner is seeking a way of running CoffeeScript without the use of JS as an intermediate language, which of course `coffee` does behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

There is, to my knowledge, only one CoffeeScript interpreter that does not compile it to JavaScript: [Poetics](https://github.com/brixen/poetics).

It's written in pure Ruby and runs CoffeeScript code directly on the Rubinius VM. However, it hasn't been updated since May, and it's far from identical to the official CoffeeScript implementation.

Comment: I think I've also seen a pure JS one on GH and on the coffee mailinglist.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to run your script with the `coffee` command, you can always add a hashbang to the top of the script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/coffee
```

As long as the file is set to be executable (`chmod +x foo.coffee`), now you can run it without specifying the `coffee` command in your terminal:

```
$ ./foo.coffee
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually work. It still interprets as bash for some reason. Can you confirm that this works for you? Thanks

Comment: this really turns me crazy—ITS NOT WORK. why?? i don't know. the solution i've found is to say `#!/usr/bin/env node /path/to/coffee-script/bin/coffee`, which is sorta nasty.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.. running on Mac OS 10.9.2

Comment: The `#!` shebang feature requires an actual binary executable as the interpreter; since `coffee` is itself also a script, it won't work.  If there were a set of command-line options you could supply to `node` that would cause it to go into "coffee mode", you could do that with the shebang..

Comment: Use: `#!/usr/bin/env coffee` you must have the coffeescript cli installed globally with npm

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `coffee` as a script interpreter directly, because it's already a script.  But you can fix that by writing a simple C wrapper:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    execvp("coffee", argv);
}
```

Compile that and put it in your PATH somewhere (I called it `klatsh`) and then put `#!/usr/bin/env klatsh` (or whatever you called it) at the top of your scripts, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use:

```
$ coffee test.coffee 
Output from coffee!
```